# Header in SOAP Request in jaxws is not sent

Tags: soap, header

I am trying to send a Header together with a SOAP request using this code (as found in this forum):

public void clientInit()
    {
     try 
    {

```
    service = new User_Service(getURL("http://10.56.100.10:8081/UserServices/UserServices?wsdl"), new QName("http://ws.userservices.sac.com/", "UserServices"));
    port = service.getUserServicesPort();
    WSBindingProvider bp = (WSBindingProvider)port;
    bp.setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create(new QName("simpleHeader"),"username"));
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    error("Failed to create URL in Online Medition Client: " + exception.getMessage());
    }


   factory=new ObjectFactory();
```

However, the Header still does not get into the Request:

POST /SubscriberServices/SubscriberServices HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://soap.sac.com"
User-Agent: Metro/2.1 (branches/2.1-6728; 2011-02-03T14:14:58+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.3 JAXWS/2.2
Host: 10.56.100.10:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 826

...................................................................

I have seen also people advising to use :

Headers.create(jaxbContext,myJaxbObject) in the setOutboundHeaders , but I do not really understand what is this used for . (I am quite new to Java...)
Can someone please advise?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards,
Dan